# How to resolve TypeError: jasmine.getEnv() is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor, cucumber

I am using protractor with jasmine to generate reports after test execution, as part of that, I am calling `jasmine.getEnv()` in my conf.js file.

However while running tests with command `ng e2e` I am seeing the following error:

```
[06:09:32] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: jasmine.getEnv is not a function
    at onPrepare (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\e2e\protractor.conf.js:33:23)
    at q_1.Promise (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:46:49)
    at Function.promise (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)
    at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:38:16)
    at plugins_.onPrepare.then (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:98:27)
    at _fulfilled (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (E:\Projects\ProtractorDemo\workspace\frontend\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:9)
[06:09:32] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

Note: when I found other threads here, answers are jasmine in latest version is not updated getEnv() method and asked to downgrade. I followed the same in my project but no luck.

Also note that, I am using cucumber with `protractor v5.4.2` and `jasmine v2.7.0`

Any suggestions please.?

Edit: Attaching conf.js file

```
    var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
    var reportDirectory = './e2e/reports';
    var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
    var reportDirectory = './e2e/reports';

    var ScreenshotAndStackReporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
        dest: reportDirectory,
        filename: 'E2ETestingReport.html',
        reportTitle: "E2E Testing Report",
        showSummary: true,
        reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
        captureOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
    });

    exports.config = {
      //seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
      allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
      getPageTimeout: 30000,
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',

      beforeLaunch: function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            ScreenshotAndStackReporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
        });
      },

      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
          'args': ['disable-infobars', '--headless', '--no-sandbox']
         }
      }, 
      cucumberOpts: {
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
        require: ['./src/steps/**/*.steps.ts', './src/support/*.ts'],
        tags: "@Smoke",
        format: 'pretty',
        profile: false,
      },
      directConnect: true,

      framework: 'custom',
      frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
      onPrepare() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        require('ts-node').register({
          project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(ScreenshotAndStackReporter);
      },
      specs: ['./src/features/**/*.feature']
    };
```

Edit #2: package.json contains the modules with versions

```
"devDependencies":  {
 ----
 ----
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
 "protractor": "^5.4.2",
 "cucumber": "^5.1.0",
 "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
 ----
 ----
}
"dependencies": {
  -----
  -----
  "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.4.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.1.1",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
  -----
  -----
}
```

Comment: At what point in your lifecycle are you calling `jasmine.getEnv()`. The global variables, such as `jasmine`, `protractor` and `browser`, are only available from the `beforeLaunch` onward.

Comment: @DublinDev: I have already have beforeLaunch. Attached the conf js file, please have a glance.

Comment: @FayazMd Could you confirm your specs path is correct?

Comment: @Madhan: Yes, because tests are running fine, I am trying to integrate reports now but failing.